# Creating a project in Layered Architecture in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

I am a developer who has developed applications in Java from the beginning. But now I have to switch into C#. Even though those two languages are quite similar, I find it difficult to get used with the IDE; which is the `Visual Studio.`

I have used `Eclipse` and `NetBeans` for the projects I have done using Java. Coming from them, I find the Visual Studio environment different in big manner.

I am trying to develop a simple application which has 3 separate layers of coding like `Model-View-Controlle`r. In fact I am developing a WPF application. In that, I need my view code to be in a one layer, data models and all the database related stuff in another separate layer and the code in between the View and the model in a separate layer.

In java, When we use `Eclipse` or `NetBeans`, what we do is we create 3 separate packages for those 3 layers. But I cannot figure out how to create different packages in `Visual Studio`. As I see, in `C#`, `namespaces` are used instead of packages. Isn't it? But I don't know how to create different namespaces and different classes in those namespaces. (Just like we create a new class inside the packages created in Eclipse)

I am bit confused here in this case. How can I create different packages (or namespaces) in `Visual Studio` & how to create the project structure as I need ?

Thank You..!

Comment: How you best tackle your project depends largely on strategic decisions. AFAIK, in java there is no concept of "binary components". It is (and I am no java expert at all), just a bunch of jar files (zip files?!). In .NET, you need to decide at some point if you want to have all your tiers (layers) in one binary unit or if you rather want to create DLLs for each tier.

Comment: Maybe a book like: http://www.amazon.de/Pro-WPF-Silverlight-MVVM-Model-View-ViewModel/dp/1430231629 could be useful to you.